# The w3schools.com example for ajax file read from server works in IE9 but not FF12

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to read the contents of a text file from the server and parse the contents with JavaScript, in order to add elements to the page depending on the contents.

But, the example at [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_examples.asp)
works great in FF12 but if I copy the source from the left-pane of the example to an .html file, and create the required data file "demo_ajax_load.txt" in the same directory as my .html, it doesn't work. However, it works okay in IE9.

Here's the source:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $.get("demo_ajax_load.txt", function(result){
      $("div").html(result);
    });
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div><h2>Let AJAX change this text</h2></div>
<button>Change Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You talk about using jQuery, yet you don't use the very nice jQuery ajax builtins?

Comment: You'll make your life a lot easier if you use a library like jQuery to handle Ajax for you.

Comment: Sorry, guys, I posted the wrong code.  I just corrected it.
How do I know if I'm using the correct Jquery.js file?
Mine is:   * jQuery JavaScript Library v1.7.1

Comment: It also does not work in Chrome.

Comment: Are you running this from the file system? IOW, is your address in IE9 something like "C:\test.html"? IIRC, IE is the only browser that allows AJAX calls to local files. You may need to run this from a web server for it to work correctly.

Comment: please use another site...not w3schools!

Comment: To all you W3Schools haters. Yeah sure some stuff is incorrect, but it is still a great site, bringing together a wealth of information, for learning all the basics.

Comment: @TimBJames: No it is not. If you want a "great site with lots of information", use MDN. You also wouldn't use a school book that contains quite some extremely outdated or just wrong statements. Imagine a history book where Germany is still ruled by Hitler (ok, that's kind of exaggerated).

Comment: @ThiefMaster School curriculum is always outdated for the beginnings of knowledge. Then they tell you everything which they taught you was actually incorrect, and this is how it should be :P

Comment: Yes, but at w3schools nobody tells you something is outdated or just bad. http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp still used a string instead of a function for `setTimeout` for example...

Comment: Umm... what's the question here?  Your current code looks like it'd work fine.  Is your file name right?  `demo_ajax_load.txt` compared to `ajax_info.txt`?  Maybe you need to use `'/demo_ajax_load.txt'` instead?

Comment: Hey wait! You say "I created the required ajax_info.txt" etc. but in the code you say `demo_ajax_load.txt`. Could you correct that?

Comment: Thanks.  I updated the post.   
W3SCHOOLS.COM:   Please recommend the best site with JavaScript, HTML, AJAX, etc. tutorials, reference, and running examples for everything.

Comment: Stand by for the bizarre:
It works okay if the web server is vxworks.
(I'm developing an embedded web site for a 20GbE laser communication system.)
But it fails if I run it from Windows.  That is, if I click-and-drag the .htm from Windows Explorer to FireFox12, it fails.  If I drag it to IE9, it works.  If I browse FF12 to my vxworks server, which reaches back into Windows through vxworks 6.9 Workbench, then it works.
So, I am good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Using vxworks instead of Windows, solved the problem.